# How to display error message correctly from custom hook validation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have a multi-step form. Currently, the parent component, is getting the state data through props passed down to the form components. The submit button is within the parent component. This works and the steps work. However, when clicking on an input field, when  it loses focus, it triggers the error message of every field within the multi-step form instead of the field that triggered the error being the only field with the error. I'm using the `error` prop of the `<TextField/>` to trigger the error visuals for the user. The fields are also validated in `validateAuth.js` and values are processed in `useFormValidation.js`. I'm also stuck on submitting the user sign up form data from the parent components state from one submit button within the parent component.

I've already tried to set errors={errors} and use if statements within useEffect hooks such as

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (props.errors) {
    setErr(true)
  }
}, [err, props.errors]);
```

However, that's resulted in my entire page loading with errors displayed without any user input.

Here's a code sandbox with a similarity to my exact development set up.

Code is the same, just simplified with the bare essentials.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-custom-authentication-final-8ldcw

Expected Results: Multi-Step Form loads, validates fields each time user tries to go to the next step by clicking Next, if there is an error, show the field that caused the error in red only and display the error text through material-ui helpertext. User should not be able to go to the next step when an error occurs on a input field within that step. When a field shows an error, the rest of the fields that were not in error, remain in their normal non-erroneous state. On last step, Verify button submits user data for sign up.

Actual: Form is erroring all fields once any input field is clicked then the user clicks anywhere else and causes the field to lose focus. Users are able to click freely through the steps of sign up regardless of errors.

Comment: One note about the code in question (not in codesandbox) - dependencies array should contain `useEffect(..., [props.errors])` as per [react-hooks/exhaustive-deps](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) eslint rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your `validateAuth.js`, this code will check all the input as a whole. The first time you call this function, all input values are empty, that's why you got the error in all input. I think this kind of code is suitable if you have all input in the same page and validate when submit button is pressed.
But, in your case you should change your validation to check on individual input value like this

```
export default function validateAuth(input) {
 let errors = {};
 switch (input.key) {
 case "email": {
  if (!input.value) {
    errors.email = "Required Email";
  } else if (
    !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i.test(input.value)
  ) {
    errors.email = "Invalid email address";
  }
  return errors;
 }
 case "password": {
  if (!input.value) {
    errors.password = "Required Password";
  } else if (input.value.length < 6) {
    errors.password = "Password must be at least 6 characters";
  }
  return errors;
 }
 case "username": {
  if (!input.value) {
    errors.username = "Required Username";
  } else if (input.value.length < 6) {
    errors.username = "Username must be 6-12 characters";
  }
  return errors;
 }
 case "verify": {
  if (!input.value) {
    errors.verify = "Required Verification";
  } else if (input.value.length < 1) {
    errors.verify = "Please input the 4 digit code.";
  }
  return errors;
 }
 default:
   return errors;
 }
}
```

Then, you should also change your `handleBlur` function to send only a single input value

```
function handleBlur(e) {
 const { name, value } = e.target;
 const input = {
  key: name,
  value
 };
 const validationErrors = validate(input);
 setErrors({
  ...errors,
  ...validationErrors
 });
}
```

Then, you should add a check on error object to enable/disable your next button

[image: Edit Hooks Custom Authentication Final]

Comment: Thnak you for your help! Here's the final version after I made some edits to the 'Next' button.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-custom-authentication-final-qu7gm